# More efficient way to pack an arbitrarily long number into 7-bit chunks?

Tags: typescript, bitwise-operators, bigint

I'm designing a binary protocol where I have a need to specify the length of a chunk of data (of arbitrary length) before providing the data itself.

I cannot use a terminator character (like a c-string) because the binary data which follows might include that character, and the process of escaping / unescaping would be computationally expensive.

In almost all cases, the length of the data is small (less than 128 bytes), but in some cases it's much larger, and I want to be as efficient as possible.

I've adopted a simplified version of the UTF-8 bit packing process where:

- Data is divided into 7-bit chunks
- The first bit of each byte indicates whether it's the last byte (0 = last byte, 1 = more bytes to follow)

This means that numbers of 127 or less can be written and read trivially, but larger numbers are more complex.

This is how i'm doing the bit packing:

```
public writePackedNumber(num: bigint | number): void
{
    if (num < 128)
    {
        this.writeUInt8(Number(num));
        return;
    }
    
    let bitString = BigInt(num).toString(2);
    const bitLength = bitString.length;
    const blocks = Math.ceil(bitLength / 7);

    // Pad the bit string to be divisible by 7
    const remainder = blocks * 7 - bitLength;
    if (remainder > 0)
    {
        bitString = '0'.repeat(remainder) + bitString;
    }

    for (let x = 0; x < bitString.length; x = x + 7)
    {
        // The first bit in every byte is a continuation indicator
        // 0 = last byte
        // 1 = more bytes to follow
        let byte = parseInt(bitString.substring(x, x + 7), 2);
        if (x + 7 !== bitString.length)
        {
            byte = byte | 0x80;
        }
        this.writeUInt8(byte);
    }
}
```

And this is how the unpacking is done:

```
public readPackedNumber(): bigint | number
{
    let byte = this.readUInt8();
    if (byte < 128)
    {
        return byte;
    }
    let finalNumber = BigInt(byte & ~ 0x80);
    while (byte & 0x80)
    {
        byte = this.readUInt8();
        finalNumber = finalNumber << 7n;
        finalNumber += BigInt(byte & ~ 0x80);
    }
    if (finalNumber <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
    {
        return Number(finalNumber);
    }
    return finalNumber;
}
```

However, my concern is the packing process, particularly `BigInt(num).toString(2)` and the string operations in that function which are likely to be a performance hog.

Ideally, I would like to find a way to do this without binary/string conversions, whilst maintaining support for `bigint` - there's no Math.log2 function for bigint, and the ones I've found online just do `toString(2)` also.

Can anyone come up with any performance improvements?

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE to demonstrate, along with use cases?  If you would like someone to suggest an alternative algorithm, it would be very helpful if they could test it against a set of known input/outputs so that we all agree on correctness.  If I have to start writing the rest of your class then it's extra work for me, plus I might get it wrong.  Personally I think you should get rid of `readUInt8` and `writeUInt8` and replace it with outputting and inputting from some array so we can compare easily

Comment: It's too bad you are using big-endian numbers, since modulo 128 and shifting right by 7 bits has to be more efficient if you really care about this, like [that](https://tsplay.dev/NlEp5m).  Of course measuring performance is tricky anyway, you'd probably need some truly gargantuan bigints or very very many of them before you noticed much of a difference.